# Unity 5.3. publishing 2d game

Tags: c#, 2d, publish

I'm having trouble with using Unity Cloud for publishing my game on WebGL player. I have been waiting over 3 hours and this is the error I get:

> Player export failed. Reason: Error building Player:
>   UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Default WebGL" is
>   denied.

Am I supposed to build the game in Unity for WebGL? When I go to Build Settings on Unity, I can't access any button in WebGL section, because

> No WebGL module is loaded.

And there's only one active button to open the download page, but it lead me to an error page.

Answer (score 0):

Try building it on Unity Web Player.

Comment: This should be a comment; it is not an answer.

Comment: I cant comment yet.